# Github Actions base64 encoding masking only one specific string

Tags: bash, github-actions

I am facing a weird issue with github action. I am simply trying to do base64 encoding over some text but the same is throwing an error when I implement it as a step. What's more weird is that this failure of base64 encoding is just for this value:

```
'{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}'
```

as I am able to successfully encode other values. I have tried the same code on my local machine as well and it works perfectly fine.

## Code Snippet:

```
header='{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}'
encoded_header=$(echo -n "$header" | base64 | tr -d '=' | tr -d '\n' | tr '+/' '-_')
echo $encoded_header
```

## Expected output:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
```

## Actual Output:

`***`

Any help with this will be really awesome!

## Code Snippet for reproduction:

```
header='{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}'
encoded_header=$(echo -n "$header" | base64 | tr -d '=' | tr -d '\n' | tr '+/' '-_')
echo $encoded_header
```

## Expected output:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
```

## Actual Output:

`***`

## Things that I have tried

- Storing the variable as configuration variable. Same result
- Storing the variable as environment variable and then encoding. Same result.
- Adding leading and trailing spaces. This does generate an encoded value but not what I need.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#redacting-secrets-from-workflow-run-logs , https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#using-secrets

Comment: To expand on that, this is what happens when you try to log a secret, but you don't mention anything about secrets. There are also some actions that mask certain strings, but again, that depends on the context.